# Не хватает оперативной памяти

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Необходимо загрузить файл, который весит около 16 ГБ в оперативную память (в дальнейшем, нужные данные оттуда считаю и вставлю в обычный текстовый файл, но это уже другая история). Делаю я это с помощью следующей команды:

```
import gensim

w2v_fpath = "all.norm-sz500-w10-cb0-it3-min5.w2v"
w2v = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(w2v_fpath, binary=True, unicode_errors='ignore')
w2v.init_sims(replace=True)
for word, score in w2v.most_similar(u"дерево"):
    print word, score
```

(взято с https://nlpub.ru/Russian_Distributional_Thesaurus?ysclid=lfhz42q3an380561492)

На моём компьютере 16 ГБ оперативной памяти + я задал 20 ГБ файла подкачки. Тем не менее, после того, как оперативная память достигает своего максимума (а именно, 16 ГБ), компьютер намертво зависает (смотрю это через "Диспетчер задач" -> "Производительность" -> "Память"). Код запускаю через `jupyter notebook`, работаю на `Windows 10`.

P.S. Выдержка с сайта

Системные требования для комфортной работы с векторами слов
Всего модель содержит более 7 миллионов векторов размерности 500 измерений, поэтому для загрузки модели в память мы рекомендуем использовать компьютер с как минимум 24 Гб оперативной памяти (модель занимает 17-19 Гб оперативной памяти, но работа возможна и с 16 Гб оперативной памяти при наличии файла подкачки достаточного объема). Общее время загрузки полной модели составляет около 200-240 секунд, модель занимает около 17-19 Гб оперативной памяти.

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что с этим можно что-то сделать. Теоретически то вы можете часть памяти в файл подкачки отправить, но своповать будет дико, что вы собственно и наблюдаете. И не факт, что система из этого состояния нормально выйдет. Хотя можете попробовать поставить параметр `datatype=np.float16`, это может сократить расход памяти в 2 раза, хотя и ухудшит точность векторов. Но что делать. Только не забудьте подключить `Numpy`: `import numpy as np`.

Comment: А `mmap` не получится использовать?

Comment: Я в питон только-только вкатился и не разбираюсь, как использовать это. Предполагаю, что `load_word2vec_format` вызывает под капотом где-то метод `open` для открытия файла, но он ведь и преобразует эти данные в какой-то свой формат

Comment: Нашёл вот такое решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65179935. Можно попробовать не загружать весь файл, а хотя-бы его часть. Как костыльное решение - покатит, но вопрос остаётся открытым

Comment: Да, `limit=` тоже можно но для начала попробуйте всё же тип урезать. Потому что какие векторы загрузятся, а какие нет при выставлении лимита - сложно сказать. Может нужные вам векторы загрузятся так, а может и нет, это лотерея. А если урезать тип, то должны загрузиться все, хотя точность их и пострадает. `datatype=np.float16` точно так же пишете в параметрах вызова `load_word2vec_format`, просто в конце, так же как и `binary=True` и `limit=10000`. Ну то есть: `w2v = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(w2v_fpath, binary=True, unicode_errors='ignore', datatype=np.float16)`

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо. Сможете оформить это решением? Я галочку тыкну

Comment: Так помогло в итоге, в память влезло? )

Comment: @CrazyElf Вечером протестирую. Думаю, поможет. На крайняк, попробую через GoogleColab сделать - надеюсь, у гугл хватит оперативки на серваках :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать урезать тип векторов, по умолчанию он `np.float32` согласно [документации](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format.html):

> Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(fname, fvocab=None,
> binary=False, encoding='utf8', unicode_errors='strict', limit=None,
> datatype=<type 'numpy.float32'>)

Можно задать вручную тип `np.float16`, вектора станут менее точными, но зато памяти теоретически понадобится в 2 раза меньше:

```py
import numpy as np

w2v = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(w2v_fpath, 
    binary=True, unicode_errors='ignore', datatype=np.float16)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Хотя в документации написано, что этот параметр экспериментальный, он может привести к замедлению некоторых операций и вообще применять его нужно с осторожностью:

> **datatype** (experimental) can coerce dimensions to a non-default float type (such as np.float16) ***to save memory***. (Such types may result in much slower bulk operations or incompatibility with optimized routines.)

Есть ещё параметр `limit`, он ограничивает число читаемых из файла векторов, но это лотерея - возможно, нужные вам вектора идут в начале файла, а возможно и в конце, тут как повезёт.